# Submit youtube playlist id and load playlist from id

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out how to figure out how I can put a youtube playlist ID in the text input it and submit it so the page loads the playlist ID from the input.

**HTML**

```
<div id="player"></div>
<input id="myText" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()">
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction() {
var PID = document.getElementById("myText");
var theName = PID.value;
    }
var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: { 
      listType:'playlist',
      list: 'theName'},
      height: '720',
      width: '1280',
      videoId: '',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady}
    });
  }


 function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setShuffle(true);//here is the function
      }
```

I'm thinking I have to make it reload the iframe but I'm not really sure what to do. How should I proceed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be best to use an iframe embed instead of a div as you get better / easy control over passing parameters such as a video id. So I thinks this might be what you are looking for:

```
<body>
<iframe  id="player" width="600" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/?wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1" wmode="Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<input id="myText" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
var PID = document.getElementById("myText");
var theName = PID.value;
 document.getElementById("player").setAttribute("src", 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+theName+'?autoplay=1&wmode=transparent&enablejsapi=1');

player.playVideo();;
    }
var tag = document.createElement('script');
   tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
   var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      playerVars: { 
      listType:'playlist',
      list: 'theName'
            },
      height: '720',
      width: '1280',
      videoId: '',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady}
    });
  }


 function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.setShuffle(true);//here is the function
      }
      </script>
```